# Converting between ucs2 and utf8

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, utf-8, c++14, ucs2

I am trying to convert between `utf8` and `ucs2`.

```
#include <codecvt> 
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> ucs2conv;
std::u16string ucs2 = ucs2conv.from_bytes(utf8_string);
std::string utf8_new = ucs2conv.to_bytes(ucs2);
```

unfortunately `microsoft vs2015` has a bug when using `codecvt`. Causing the following error:

> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::locale::id std::codecvt::id"

Does anyone know how to work around this bug in a way that is also viable on `linux`?

Comment: Just use `wchar_t` (which is guaranteed to have the same size as `char16_t` with VC++) with `std::wstring`.

Comment: Use the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) for all things Unicode. No, really.

Comment: This is part of a larger codebase where additional third part libraries is not a for me viable way forward I'm afraid

Comment: The linker bug was [fixed in VS 2017](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1403302/unresolved-external-when-using-codecvt-utf8). Which, btw supports up to C++17.

Comment: @Bomaz: Not having any third-party libraries at your disposal when doing C++ means you need to look for a different project. Really. The standard library is utterly *unable* to cater for everything. Fully compliant handling of Unicode conversions being one of the things it cannot do. (Favourite example: Convert `'ß'` to uppercase. The standard functions *can not do it*.)

Comment: @DevSolar actually, that's one of the improvements in C++11 onwards. There *are* UTF16 and UTF32 types and strings now (`char16_t1`, `char32_t`, `u16string`,`u32string`). The only "hole" is UTF8. UTF8 literals are available but UTF8 strings use the `char` and `string` types,

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The new types are nice, but only go 98% of the way. Composition / decomposition / normalization, for example, are not covered either (to my knowledge).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : That bug was _not_ fixed in VC++ 2017, unfortunately. (Read Steve Wishnousky's comments on the bug you linked.)

Comment: @ildjarn curses! Why did they leave it as `Fixed` then? I wonder if Linux payload in VC++ 2017 works differently.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : The Linux workload is just a remote build/debug system for GCC, so what works and what doesn't is dependent on your GCC installation.